# Dynamic Params rendering twice on next hard navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Basically what i was doing is take the params from the url to fetch data from a rest api with axios. when debugging i logged the params, but something weird kept happening. the params get logged twice and in one of the logs it returns null. i thought the problem with my project or something i wasn't aware of was causing it. so i create an empty project and tried it, and again the same problem appeared.
here are the logs
[image]

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  console.log(params);

  return <div>{params.id}</div>;
}
```

When doing hard navigation, for eg, copy pasting the link in the browser, i get the null value. but if i go to the page via the Link from next/link, the null doesn't get logged and there's one log only. Why is that ?

when doing so in codesandbox, i don't get that behavior

[https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-pond-smvt7r?file=/app/product/[id]/page.tsx:3,1](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-pond-smvt7r?file=/app/product/%5Bid%5D/page.tsx:3,1)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario. created a new next app with a dynamic param and a console.log. It works as expected. It logs once. 
Can you provide a git repo?

Comment: Yes, of course
https://github.com/Zakisb/practice-app/tree/main/app/product/%5Bid%5D

Comment: You'd laugh if you knew what was the problem.... it was a chrome extension that was causing me this error ..... I tried running the code in brave and in incognito mode in chrome, everything worked fine. Started removing extensions and disabling them, everything worked. thank you.

Comment: that what I expected

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The problem was a Chrome extension that was causing this behavior.